# :before to respect parent's padding

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to insert a logo image using css on `a` element with `background-image`.

However, I couldn't get the `a:before` box to respect `a`'s padding.

The first example in the snippet below is using `width`, `height` and `display: block` but nothing get shown at all.

So, I tried with `position: absolute` in second example. The logo is shown but it's not respecting `a`'s padding.

How do I make it so the logo fit inside the padding of `a`?

#### Current

[image: Current Logo Size]

#### Expected

[image: Expected Logo Size]

#### What I want to avoid doing

Due to responsive design requirement, I'd like the logo's size to change based on the `a`'s element size. Therefore, below are some things I'd like to avoid.

- Using fixed values to fit `.logo:before` inside `a`'s padding.
- Amending `a` styles

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { margin: 0; }

.container, .container > p, .container > .logo {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.container > p, .container > .logo {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: .3125rem;
  padding-bottom: .3125rem;
  color: transparent !important;
}

.logo:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/FF0000/000000') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.logo.absolute:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="logo">Logo</a>
  <p>Navigation links</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <a class="logo absolute">Logo</a>
  <p>Navigation links</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @Sharvan I've included a screenshot in the question. I want the logo to fit within the padding of `a`.

Comment: why you need the padding for `a`

Comment: @Sharvan It's there by design. I don't want the logo to expand to the height of `.container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `.logo:before`'s `content` is an empty string, nothing will ever be displayed unless `height` is explicitly defined with a fixed value.

`content: ' '` can fix the problem but this is just a patch rather than a root fix.

The root cause is due to `align-items: center` in `.container` which will align the content in the middle vertically with its minimum height required. A combination with empty `content` caused `.logo:before` element to not show anything at all.

The current desired behavior is wanting `.logo`'s height to match the navigation links' height, there's no need to use `align-items: center` here and `normal` should do fine.

The `position: absolute` method will always ignore padding.

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { margin: 0; }

.container, .container > p, .container > .logo {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  align-items: normal;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
  background-color: gray;
}

.container > p, .container > .logo {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: .3125rem;
  padding-bottom: .3125rem;
  color: transparent !important;
}

.logo:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/FF0000/000000') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a class="logo">Logo</a>
  <p>Navigation links</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value of top and bottom property of your logo to .3125rem;

```
.logo.absolute:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: .3125rem;
  bottom: .3125rem;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that I didn't provide enough details. Using fixed value will raise the need to adding new style and change its values everywhere including media queries as well as when the logo is fixed up top when page is scrolled down. I'd like to avoid doing this but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the padding for `logo` and added `min-height: 28px;` to your background image. Looking forward to further question.

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body { margin: 0; }

.container, .container > p, .container > .logo {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.container > p, .container > .logo {
  flex-basis: auto;
  flex-grow: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  /*padding-top: .3125rem;
  padding-bottom: .3125rem;*/
  color: transparent !important;
}

.logo:before {
  content: '';
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150x100/FF0000/000000') no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  min-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <a class="logo">Logo</a>
    <p>Navigation links</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <a class="logo absolute">Logo</a>
    <p>Navigation links</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this earlier and thanks for your answer but there are some cases where the `a.logo`'s size is reduced in height when the page is scrolled down. With this, the logo stayed at that size when it should be reduced in size which is not desirable.